# Issue with Ghost theme at my work website - sidebar is not mobile responsive

Tags: css, ghost-blog

I've been ask at work to fix an issue with our website.I didn't created it so I have to understand what cause this bug but some help will be appreciate.
In Screen PC, the website is working fine ; on mobile when you click to open the sidebar, you click on Services, the submenu opens fine : [image]

But when you click below on Industries, this it what appears :
[image]

I download the theme installed on Ghost and check the css file, I think there and issue with bootstrap but I'm not sure...

If someone can give me some tips or idea - Let me know if should put some code here of this portion.

Thank you

```
enter code here

/*------INDUSTRIES-SUBMENU------*/

#content-desktop {display: block;}
#content-mobile {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

#industries-submenu ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px 0 40px 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    position: relative;
}
#industries-submenu ul li{
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

#content-desktop {display: none;}
#content-mobile {display: block;}

#industries-submenu ul li a{
    color: #1a2c47;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
#industries-submenu ul li ul{
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
#industries-submenu ul li ul li{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
}
#industries-submenu ul li ul li a{
    color: #4f5661;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
}

/*===== 2. INDUSTRIES =====*/

.breadcrumbs-blog .breadcrumb-item.active:last-child:before{
    content: 'Blog';
    margin-left: 4px;
    display: block;
    color: #1a2c47;
}
#breadcrumb-section{
    border-top: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    padding: 25px 0 50px 0;
}
.breadcrumb{
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.breadcrumb .breadcrumb-item{
    padding: 0;
}
.breadcrumb li a{
    color: #0e50b2;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.breadcrumb li a:after{
    width: 5px;
    height: 8px;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url('../img/icon-arrow-small.svg');
    margin: 0 5px 1px;
}
.breadcrumb-item+.breadcrumb-item::before{
    display: none;
}
.breadcrumb-item.active {
    color: #1a2c47;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: flex;
    line-height: 22px;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
#page-content .post-title{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 48px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#page-content .featured-image{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.editor-content h1,
.editor-content h2,
.editor-content h3,
.editor-content h4,
.editor-content h5,
.editor-content h6{
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.editor-content h1{
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 48px;
}
.editor-content h2{
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 38px;
}
.editor-content h3{
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 34px;
}
.editor-content h4{
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
.editor-content h5{
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.editor-content h6{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
.editor-content p{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.editor-content a:not(.btn){
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.editor-content ul,
.editor-content ol{
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}
.editor-content ul li{
    list-style-type: disc;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.editor-content ol li{
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.editor-content img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.editor-content table{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 30px 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.editor-content td, 
.editor-content th {
    padding: .75rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
.editor-content .table-holder{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

/*-----SIDEBAR-----*/

.sidebar{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-get-a-quote{
    background-color: #082e69;
    position: relative; 
    padding: 60px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url('../img/sidebar-illustration-1.svg');
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-get-a-quote .get-a-quote-info{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-get-a-quote .get-a-quote-info h3{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-get-a-quote .get-a-quote-info .btn{
    font-size: 18px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-associated-links{
    background-color: #f8f8f8; 
    padding: 25px 20px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-associated-links h3{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-associated-links ul{
    margin: 0;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-associated-links ul li{
    margin-bottom: 15px; 
}
.sidebar .sidebar-associated-links ul li:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-associated-links ul li a{
    line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #0e50b2;
    display: block;
}
.sidebar .list-boxed .parent{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.sidebar .list-boxed li ul li{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
}
.sidebar p,
.sidebar ul li,
.sidebar ol li{
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
}

.widget{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.widget h3{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidebar .latest-posts{
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin: 0;
}

.sidebar .latest-posts li a{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.sidebar .latest-posts li:last-child a{
    border: none;
}

#big-get-a-quote{
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 120px 0;
    background-color: #082e69;
    background-image: url('../img/big-get-a-quote.png');
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#big-get-a-quote h3{
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 48px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#big-get-a-quote p:first-of-type{
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 34px;
}

#big-get-a-quote .btn{
    margin: 50px auto 0;
}

.editor-content img,
.editor-content .kg-width-full img,
.editor-content .kg-width-wide img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.editor-content .kg-gallery-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 10px auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 5;
}

.editor-content .kg-gallery-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

.editor-content .kg-gallery-image img {
    display: flex;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.editor-content .kg-gallery-row:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.editor-content .kg-gallery-image:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.editor-content figcaption{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
}

.loop .post{
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.loop .post .post-inner-content{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.loop .inner{
    position: relative;
}

.post .img-holder {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.post .img-holder .featured-image{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.post .img-holder .featured-image:before{
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
}

#page-content .post .img-holder .featured-image{
    margin: 0;
}

.post .inner-featured-image{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.loop .post:hover .img-holder .featured-image{
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}

.loop h3{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#load-posts{
    display: flex;
    width: 180px;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

#load-posts.finish{
    width: 260px;
    opacity: .5;
}

.manual-tags{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.manual-tags a{
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.loop-news .item:first-child .post{
    border-top: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.loop-news .post{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.loop-news .inner{
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.loop-news .post-inner-content{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.loop-news .post-inner-content .post-meta{
    min-width: 150px;
    text-align: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .sidebar .sidebar-get-a-quote .get-a-quote-info .btn {
        font-size: 14px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    #stats ul li p{
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    #stats ul li p b{
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    #industries ul li a{
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 1.2;
    }
    #why-obelis .blockquote p{
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 28px;
    }
    #stats ul li .img-inner{
        width: 54px;
        height: 54px;
    }
    .home-video iframe[src*="https://www.youtube.com/"] {
        height: calc(210px / 1.77777778) !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .navigation-trigger,
    .mobile-nav,
    .mobile-backdrop{
        display: block;
    }
    .mobile-nav .logo img{
        width: 200px;
        height: 62px;
    }
    header .topbar{
        display: none;
    }
    header .nav {
        padding: 10px;
    }
    header .menu .nav {
        display: none;
    }
    .navigation-trigger{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .mobile-backdrop{
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 998;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    .mobile-nav{
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 300px;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 999;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        background: #fff;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    .menu-active .mobile-backdrop{
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        pointer-events: all;
    }
    .menu-active .mobile-nav{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    header .mobile-nav .topbar{
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 44px;
    } 
    header .mobile-nav .nav{
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
    }
    header .mobile-nav .logo{
        padding: 15px;
    }
    header .nav ul{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    header .nav ul li a{
        display: flex;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #f8f8f8;
        color: #143074;
        font-weight: 600;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    header .nav ul li a:focus,
    header .nav ul li a:hover{
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    header .nav ul li .btn{
        margin: 15px;
    }
    header .topbar .container{
        padding: 0;
    }
    header .topbar .search-btn{
        display: none;
    }
    header .topbar .header-top{
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    header .topbar .header-top ul{
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    header .topbar ul li{
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    header .topbar ul li a{
        display: flex;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        line-height: 24px;
    }
    header .mobile-nav{
        overflow: auto;
    }
    header .mobile-nav .search{
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 44px;
        pointer-events: all;
    }
    header .mobile-nav .search input{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    header .mobile-nav ul li a i{
        display: none;
    }
    header .mobile-nav ul li a[data-submenu] i{
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    #services .inner .service-holder p{
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 24px;
    }
    .industries-and-services .col-industries ul li{
        width: 100%;
    }
    #stats{
        overflow: auto;
    }
    #stats ul{
        min-width: 1000px;
        padding-right: 30px;
    }
    #about-us-section .who-we-are:before{
        width: 100vw;
        right: 50%;
        transform: translateX(50%);
    }
    #about-us-section .who-is-it-for .inner {
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    .submenu{
        display: none !important;
    }
    header .mobile-nav .submenu{
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        padding: 0;
    }
    header .mobile-nav .active .submenu{
        display: block !important;
    }
    header .mobile-nav .submenu p,
    header .mobile-nav .submenu p + a,
    header .mobile-nav .submenu .link{
        display: none;
    }
    #industries-submenu ul{
        margin: 0;
    }
    #industries-submenu ul li {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
    }
    .submenu h3{
        margin: 0;
    }
    header .nav ul li .submenu a{
        padding: 15px 30px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #aeb3bd;
        margin-left: -15px;
        width: calc(100% + 30px);
        line-height: 1;
        color: #143074;
    }
    .submenu-style-1 {
        padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
    }
    header .search .btn{
        top: 2px;
        transform: none;
        right: 17px;
    }
    .list-boxed .parent{
        width: calc(50% - 30px);
    }
    .safer-markets ul li{
        width: 100%;
        flex: auto;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        border: none;
    }
    .home-video{
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    .home-video iframe[src*="https://www.youtube.com/"] {
        height: calc(510px / 1.77777778) !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    .why-obelis ul{
        padding: 40px 20px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .intro{
        padding: 60px 0 100px 0;
    }
    .intro h1{
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .intro p{
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    #why-obelis{
        padding: 50px 0;
    }
    #about-us-section .who-is-it-for{
        padding: 50px 0;
    }
    #about-us-section .inner {
        padding: 50px 0;
    }
    #about-us-section .who-is-it-for .inner{
        padding: 0;
    }
    .list-posts ul li b{
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
    }
    footer .footer-bottom ul{
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .banner .text-right{
        display: flex;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    #services .features li{
        width: 100%;
    }
    #services .inner .row:before, #services .inner .row:after,
    #services .inner:before{
        display: none;
    }
    #services .inner .service-holder{
        padding: 30px 0;
    }
    #services .features{
        margin: 0;
    }
    #services .inner{
        border: none;
    }
    .section-title{
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    .list-boxed .parent{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 15px 15px;
    }
    .industries-and-services {
        margin: 0 0 50px 0;
    }
    .loop .post .post-inner-content{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .loop-news .post-inner-content .post-meta{
        text-align: left;
    }
    .loop-news .post{
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
    #why-obelis .blockquote{
        padding: 60px 30px;
    }
    header .nav .menu .logo img,
    .mobile-nav .logo img {
        width: 100px;
        height: auto;
    }
    footer .footer-top{
        padding: 20px 0;
    }
    .home-video iframe[src*="https://www.youtube.com/"] {
        height: calc((100vw - 30px) / 1.77777778) !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, without code it will be difficult to find the problem. Secondly, one guess of mine: Check the classes of the elements on the mobile version, which shouldn't be shown. And simply hide it's elements for mobile resolutions. But as said, without code it's difficult to tell.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply :-) Here the CSS code inside the Ghost Theme:

Comment: I added this CSS code in industries submenu but still not works.. < br >#content-desktop {display: block;}
#content-mobile {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

Comment: hmm, do you have some link where I can look at? Or JSFiddle?

Comment: This is the website [link](https://www.obelis.net/) - On pc with firefox, pressing control + Shift +m, you can test it as if it was in a mobile

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - but I think, you are able to solve it by your own, as you know better the structure of your project.

1. Open your Link with Chrome (or Firefox)
2. Press F12 and select the mobile resolution:
   Here you can open the mobile menu and see the bug, as shown in your picture
3. Now try to change the width of the resolution in Chrome:
   You will see, that the bug will be automatically fixed

When looking at the HTML and CSS in Developer Tools, while doing these steps, you will see, that they change. Therefore you have to look at, what is changing and try to find a solution here.

My guess in your case is that some CSS values are wrongly set at the beginning (maybe while initializing the page dynamically??).

**UPDATE:**

It seems, that the `top` CSS attribute in your `li` tag (`parent sub-industries` classes) causes the problem (which seems to be dynamically calculated).

Hope I could help!

Comment: Thank you for your reply and explanation.

Comment: But as it is not my project, it's more difficult :-) yes, I've follow your explanation and yes the bug is fixed when you change the width. But I still have two issue because I don't know which attribute in CSS I have to modify and what to modify ? Is it in this one : `code` header .mobile-nav ul li a i{
        display: none;
    }
    header .mobile-nav ul li a[data-submenu] i{
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

Comment: No - As written, I'm pretty sure that the problem is the `top` attribute in your `parent sub-industries` elements. These attributes are set dynamically. For example, it's `top: 0px;`for the first element, `top: 167px;` for the second element and so on. And these values are missing, when you open the submenu the first time. As mentioned, I don't know, what your project looks like. I would check the HTML file of the mobile menu and look, if there is some additional JavaScript, which is setting the `top` attribute of your `parent sub-industries` elements.

Comment: well thank you, I'm sure you are right. I found an HTML file for the industries submenu and main.js file but there is no "top" attribute in them...I think I will call for a webdevelopper to fix it. Thanks again

Comment: and I just notice that it seems also an issue of overlapping between industrie submenu and about us submenu in mobile version. too complicated for my skills